# Unity 5.6: Ipad ios screenshot image path

Tags: ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I would like to write a screenshot function when it's triggered, it will store screenshot in the ipad photo.

This is the function, it fails. May I know which save path should I use?
Application.CaptureScreenshot("/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/screenshot.png");

Comment: You need an Object-C plugin to save to the photo path.

Comment: can not simply use Application.CaptureScreenshot to fulfill? or which Object-C plugin should I use?

Comment: You can save it to the device without a plugin. If you want to save it where iPhone usually save its images from the camera then that's when you need a plugin which you can develop with Object-C or use/buy one from the Assetstore.

Comment: so if I save it without a plugin just by code "Application.CaptureScreenshot("/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/screenshot.png");"  then I can not save it to the place ipad usually save its images from the camera?